# Delete Environment Property from UDeploy

Tags: udeploy

Has anyone found a way to delete an environment property from UDeploy via a REST call?  I grabbed the call made via the UDeploy site when I delete a variable in Environment=>Configuration=>Environment Properties but I get a "Conflict" each time I attempt it.

Thanks for your thoughts,
Patrick``

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/urbancode-deploy/7.0.5?topic=commands-removeenvironmentproperty

If there's an old name of property (i.e. without `p:` prefix) in the call, rest call might return 'Conflict'. Please see Warning: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/urbancode-deploy/7.1.1?topic=properties-referring

Comment: Thanks for your reply Greenmarker, This sounded really promising but so far playing with all kinds of variations on the variable name I get back either a BadRequest or Conflict via the REST api. Much appreciated though!